# How should images be saved using express? Database, or just file?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, multer, ng-file-upload

I am using basically the mean stack. I'm also using multer but I am trying to see what the best practices are. Using Angular I can upload photos fine and they are going to a folder on my file system. From here I can just view them. However I'm wondering what the best practices are. Should I save the image url to a database along with the size and other properties or should I just pull them from the client? I've seen some solutions but they were from about 2 years ago so I wanted to make sure I'm current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used ng-file-upload upload on the angular part and Multer on the node.js part to handle images for my system.

The method is appropriate and you can go ahead without any doubt.

Most of the websites on the internet follow the same method, they save the images in the file disk system and then they save it's url in the respective database.

Using multer you can have all information required for a photo and the module is really flexible with a lot many options.

I think you should go ahead with what you have in mind. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks. I did alot of research but not sure which method to go with. I will proceed with this method.

Comment: Best of luck. Tag me when you run into problems because I did face a lot of them when I started.

Answer (score 1):

You just save the image url from the directory, where image is stored. If you need any information, you can get the information from the image where image is stored (Get image from url). So just save image url into database.